# I still get "Googlebot can't access your site" messages after removing a site from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, crawl-errors

I had a client who moved their site a while back to another developer. When they moved it they took down the site and put up a coming soon page ( which is currently what's there). Googlebot warned me that it couldn't reach the site so I logged into My Webmaster tools and removed the site from it, but I continue to get messages saying it can't access the site.

Is there some way I can communicate this scenario to Google. I really thought that removing it from my webmaster tools would have done the trick.  I'd rather not put the Google email address in my blacklist.

Comment: I would suspect that the site is still using your old GA code. Encourage the site owner to change this. Otherwise, I would just create a rule in your client to file the messages into a folder. Annoying, but these steps are necessary sometimes.

Comment: Surely google has some way to manage this properly though, are you sure?

Comment: I have no idea. I was making a guess as to what can trigger this. Knowing code the way I do, it makes sense to me. I am sure that when you disassociated yourself from the site, it was only an association that was broken and the data record does not actually disappear completely until someone else claims the site. That is why I left a comment and not an answer. You can check the source code of the home page to see if this may be the case. Then contact the site owner and see if they can create a Google account and claim the site. Then you will know for sure.

Comment: Thanks anyway - i'll probably just add a mail rule to delete the message. I think it's pretty bad UX on google's part though for what it's worth.

Comment: Yeah. I understand. Likely the easiest thing to do quickly. I would out of curiosity see if the Google GA/WMT code at least looks familiar.

Comment: Thanks I know ... I don't actually think there even IS a new developer for the site as it's been in a coming soon state for I suppose a year now - I'm guessing it's totally dead. I'm not sure even if the company exists anymore TBH  ... I'm not in touch with the owners and anyway I don't fancy calling them up to ask them to check code their GA code as I know they wouldn't know what I was talking about.I've thought about all this before. It's not a major issue I just thought deleting it from WT should have been enough for google to know it's not operational any more.

Comment: I would have though deleting it would be good too. I spent years working to help churches, associations, charities, and small businesses apart from my day to day work. I am surprised how many businesses that had full potential squandered it then just left things a mess for others to deal with.

Comment: Is this still happening?   If Google is no longer sending these out erroneously, then we could close this question.

Comment: They seem to just have stopped for some reason several months afterwards ... I never did find a way to properly remove it though, it just seemed to have eventually given up. Not sure what you want to do about the question ... There was no answer as such.